# FileNet: TransactionRolledbackException while creating index on DB2 from FEM

Tags: db2, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I am trying to add an index to a document class' field, but - after some minutes - I receive the error `TransactionRolledBackException`.

[image]

I suspect that's because this class already has thousands of created objects. In fact, whenever I try to create a index for a new class, I do not receive this error.
I also suspected that it was just a timeout for FEM, while the index creation proceeds in the background, but this is not true, because I tried this creation 4 days ago, with no results.
Closing and reopening the FEM, the parameter always shows the missing index:

[image]

Is there some parameter to set in order to avoid the timeout, or is it possible to create an index directly on the DB2?

Comment: This error doesn't seem to be from Db2, but kind of application timeout (or firewall). Do you have any Db2 driver related error?

Comment: @adamitj: thanks for your reply, exactly, this is a message from FEM, the administrative tool of FileNet. I suspect there is a timeout for index creation on DB2. So, technically, this is not a error directly reported from DB2, but related to an operation towards it..

Comment: If it is related to Db2, probably FEM is hiding the real error message. Please ask to your DBA to check db2diag.log messages. If there is some sort of timeout or transaction log overflow, there you'll find the error message and a code, like SQL0911N (or -911) that will give you directions to to the fix.